# Jdk is using maximum memory when running through Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, memory-management, java-8

[image]

As you can see in attached image when I run start tomcat the Java is taking maximum memory. Is ther any way to optimize this memory consuption of Java.
I am using JDK 8 with eclipse Luna. Earlier when I was using JDK 7 it's memory consumption was as low as around 240MB. since I have started using JDK 8 for same application the memory consumption has been increased sometime it goes beyond 800MB.

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t see that “Java is taking maximum memory”. The only thing I see is that it takes 615.2 MB. When you say, that it can get even beyond 800 MB, then 615.2 MB is *not* the maximum. If you are asking what consumes this amount of memory, use a profiler. Note that profilers like JVisualVM are even able to *compare* heap dumps so you can find out differences between a Java 7 run and Java 8 run of your application. We can’t do that for you, we don’t have your application.

Comment: Thanks Holger, I'll take a look on "JVisualVM".